# I typed iptables -F by mistake, how to undo?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw, nmap

I typed `iptables -F` by mistake, how can I undo it?

I see now strange activity on my routers IP, scanned it and saw that strange ports are open. How can I block these ports?

Comment: See here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61957/does-iptables-f-permanently-delete-all-iptables-rules

Comment: I do not have /etc/sysconfig/iptables, I only see /etc/sysctl.d/ and systemd/

Comment: It depends,  how did you set and save your rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [This Post](https://serverfault.com/questions/254482/apply-back-firewall-after-iptables-flush) iptables -F only flushes out the currently running rule set and everything will be back after reboot.

To block ports, you can follow [This Howto](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-block-port/) or use the following (blocking incoming on port 80 as an example):

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j DROP
sudo service iptables save
```

Comment: yeah I found it out by myself with help of you guys! thanks